# How to run a ruby app which contains some python scripts(2&3) on heroku

Tags: python, ruby, heroku, buildpack

I have a Ruby app which I want to run it on Heroku.
But it contains some python code, and its structure is as below

```
|
|__ config
| 
|__ controllers
|
|__ helpers
|      |
|      |__task1.py
|      |__task2.py
| 
|
|__ models
|
|__ services
    |__callpython1.rb
    |__callpython2.rb
    |__   ....
    |__   ....
    |__   ....
```

In services directory, callpython1.rb will call task1.py ,

(use ruby code : ` python helpers/task1.py "#{Argument}" `)

And callpython2.rb will call task2.py

(use ruby code : `python3 helpers/task2.py "#{Argument}" `)

So how should I do to run such app like this which is mainly in Ruby but sometimes it
needs to call some python script on heroku?

Comment: Have you tried running it?

Comment: It works well in my local terminal, but when I put it on heroku , it just crashes (I think it's because there contains python script but I only choose Ruby for this app in the begining).

Comment: On my free tier Heroku dyno I am able to run Python: 
`Running rails console on ⬢ free-tier-dyno... up, run.9094
Loading production environment (Rails 4.2.7.1)
[1] pry(main)> \`python --version\`
Python 2.7.6
=> ""
[2] pry(main)> \`python -c 'print "hello"'\`
=> "hello\n"`
Maybe your python scripts don't support python 2?
Do you get an error in the heroku log?